# Short reference for LaTeX/MathJax commands

Tags: discussion, faq, mathjax, formatting

Some users are not familiar with the LaTeX notations, which is perfectly fine, but it would be better if we could have an FAQ/help page that explains the basic commands, in a similar way to the markdown edit-help.

We should have a short summary of basic LaTeX commands (and link to a more extensive list of commands, if needed).

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/156248).

Comment: Since this seems to be meant to serve as a canonical reference for using MathJax on this site, I've edited this question a bit to try and clean it up (e.g. so it's presented as a reference/guide, rather than a feature request). The question or answer(s) may still need further updates/improvement, but that's up to the community.

Answer (score 12):

You can enclose LaTeX math code in `$...$` for inline math, and `$$...$$` resp. for indented equations.

MathJax supports essentially the commands native to $\LaTeX$ as well as those defined by `amsmath` and `amssymb` (with some exceptions in both directions). For a complete list, see [the MathJax reference](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#).

I have found these references to be useful:

- [Wikipedia LaTeX help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula)
- [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), specifically chapters [4.1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) and [4.2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)
- [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for looking up symbols

Aside from that, my personal hints (and what I edit most):

- `\mathbb{N}` for the natural numbers; similar for other such sets.
- `\mathcal{L}` for calligraphic letters, e.g. languages
- If you prefer left-aligned non-inline formulae, use `$\qquad \displaystyle ...$` (in an own paragraph) instead of `$$ ... $$`.
- `\operatorname{name}` for long operator names (non-italic letters and spacing).
- `\mathrm{name}` or `\mathsf{name}` for dedicated names, such as P and NP (non-italic letters).
- Parentheses around big stuff (e.g. fractions) are usually undersized. Use `\left( ... \right)` (similar for `[` resp. `]` and `{` resp. `}`) to have them adapt their size accordingly.
- Use `\to`, `\iff` and `\implies` instead of `\rightarrow`, `\Leftrightarrow` and `\Rightarrow` where appropriate (i.e. semantically fitting).
- You can define [your own macros](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros.html). They survive across multiple math environments, so take care not to destroy other posts.
- Use `\text{...}` when using English in formulae.
- Use `\dots` instead of `...`.

Be aware that the spoiler tag (`!>`) does not support multiple lines -- even inside math formulae! You'll have to write all of your formula in one line when using spoiler tags.

---

#### Examples

```
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{B}$ and $a \leq b$. Then, $a + b \geq b$.

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$\qquad\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0 $$

$ \max_n f(x) = - \min_n (-f(n)) $

$L = \{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM and } M(w) = 1 \}$

Quicksort runs in $O(n\log n)$ time on average, but in $O(n^2)$ time in the worst case.

$$\begin{align*}
    a_0     &= 1 \\
    a_{n+1} &= 2 \cdot a_n + 3
\end{align*}$$

$$\chi_S(s) = \begin{cases} 
               1 &, s \in S \\
               0 &, s \notin S
             \end{cases}$$

$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    7 & 8 & 9
  \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{align*}
  S &\to (S)S \mid A \mid \varepsilon \\
  A &\to aA   \mid a
 \end{align*}$
```

Comment: There is a more elaborate [post on meta.mathematics.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Good and elegant help!

Answer (score 2):

You may use this online graphical tool to create Latex formulas:

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php