# Latex best practices

Tags: discussion, faq, mathjax, formatting

I inserted Latex in 15 questions from other users and I'm being called attention for two of them.

Then I ask:

1. What are the best practices for Latex Edit?
2. When can I use?
3. And when I can not use?

Any constructive help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit, and caring about when and how to!

Comment: Yes, thanks for the edits. However, one thing I would ask is that you check them more carefully. When I review them, I often find I have to re-edit your edits because you've left some mathematics in plain text (often single-letter variables occurring in running text) and/or tried to typeset some non-mathematics (e.g., acronyms) in LaTeX. There's no reason to write something like `$\mathrm{DFA}$` instead of `DFA`.

Comment: Also, please don't edit closed/on-hold questions unless the edit actually fixes the reason the question was put on hold. Few people are going to read on-hold questions, so improving the formatting doesn't achieve anything. Since editing the question causes it to be automatically nominated for re-opening, it takes up even more of people's time. Correspondingly, reviewers: please reject formatting-only edits to on-hold posts!

Comment: Thanks for editing the posts, and caring about the quality of the posts on the site!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I give a general introduction on what I consider good editing practice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/98).

With respect to LaTeX, specifically, I have some thoughts.

- **In titles:** the less, the better. Not only do LaTeX-heavy titles slow down
  loading of question lists, they are -- when more complex -- also all but 
  impossible to decipher in RSS feed readers and in the mobile SE app.

  A question that is hard to express without LaTeX is probably no good, anyway.
- **In posts:** most if not all formulae should be typeset with LaTeX. Period.
  Make sure you know your game, though; *bad* LaTeX is no good, either. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a quick overview and pointers.

  Outside of formulae, it's sometimes better to not use LaTeX. It's expensive to
  typeset and can also break the flow of reading (because the fonts don't quite match). Common examples would be complexity and language classes; while you would write

  > For some $L \in \mathrm{CFL} \cap X$, we can...

  you should probably stick with

  > Do CFL and NP have the same closure properties?
- **In comments:** Go easy, but use it if you need it. The same rules from posts
  apply.
- **In chat:** [I wish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97938/any-chance-of-mathjax-in-chat). Oh, wait, [ChatJax++](https://github.com/vyznev/chatjax) looks like a reasonable workaround!