# Request to Approve Edit, so I can Edit more

Tags: support, editing

### **Request to Users**

A few days back, [this query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378328/pending-edits-and-limit-on-number-of-edits) was posted, because my [suggestions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/143377/rohit-singh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) were not getting approved.

I was advised to post about suggestion on the per-site meta about it, asking more users to take part. This is thus a request to users to review the suggested edits on [my account](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/143377/rohit-singh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). So that I can actively contribute to the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your work to improve posts on this site through suggested edits!  I appreciate it.  And thank you for flagging that we are behind on reviewing suggested edits -- sorry about that.

---

In case it is helpful, I have some minor suggestions on future edits:

- It's normally better to [avoid using Latex (Mathjax) in titles](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1439/755) (I think this has been mentioned in a [comment to you](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150930/asymptotic-analysis-of-tn-2tn-8-2tn-4-n#comment317449_150930)).
- When you convert to Latex, instead of using something like `$A \text{ and } B$`, instead use `$A$ and $B$`.
- There is no need to use so much bold (e.g., words like "but" or "find" don't need to be put in bold).  I noticed that many of your edits changed words to be put in bold that I don't think need to be in bold (and that I find distracting to be in bold).  Phrases like "Turing Decidable" don't need to be in bold, and "decidable" doesn't need to be capitalized.
- Please don't change titles only to capitalize all words in the title.  There is no need for that.
- It's not necessary to make an edit just to change $T(n/4)$ to $$T\bigg(\frac{n}{4}\bigg).$$  $T(n/4)$ is fine.

Comment: Thanks for Replying. I have noted avoiding `MathJax in Titles` and `\text in $$`. Moreover, one should **not edit ONLY for** `Capitalizing all words in title` and `Fraction Formatting`.  But don't you think that when it comes to **Bold** and CAPITALIZING KEYWORDS, it varies from Person to Person? Many Users like Bold, while many do not. Same goes for Capitalizing Keywords! Thus, I guess editing **ONLY for Bold and CAPITALIZING** should be avoided, but at the same time when these edits constitute a part of major edits, it shouldn't be a issue. Thanks!

Comment: @RohitSingh, please don't use `fixed-width font` (\`...\`) for emphasis.  That should be used only for code.  Bold etc.: I do see it as an issue.  I recommend that you avoid adding bold and capitalization; or be sparing. If you are writing your own post, you can in principle use whatever style you like (I still recommend you don't use so much bold and capitals -- I find it distracting) -- but if you are editing someone else's post, do not edit it to introduce all that bold and capitals.  If it is a matter of style, you shouldn't be changing someone else's stylistic choices.

Comment: All points advised in answer are duly Noted. Is there any option to delete previous [Suggested Edits](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/143377/rohit-singh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) in order to empty the queue? Because even after 10 days of requests, no action (Accept/Reject) is being taken on Old Edit Requests, obstructing my way to Edit new posts which require serious edits. Naïve users often don't know how to format text for equations/codes/images, and require someone experienced to format post. Thus, it's a humble request to review suggested edits as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: @RohitSingh, I've reviewed a bunch of your edits.  Thank you for your work to improve posts on this site!  For the future, I wish you would not add italics, bold, and capitalization to posts in a way that differs from the original post's style, unless most people/everyone would agree that it improves clarity.  (For instance, "The initial grammar provided was" is correct, and "The Initial Grammar provided was" contains unnecessary and inappropriate capitalization.)

Comment: Thanks for the action. The instructions will be taken care for all future edits.