# Change "MathJax help" link on Markdown help page

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing, hyperlinks

The "MathJax help" link in [the "LaTeX" section of the Markdown Editing Help page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) currently leads to https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/ – but that page doesn't actually talk about MathJax.

I believe [this post on Math.SE's Meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a much better link.

---

(A staff member on Meta Stack Exchange suggested creating a question here to request this change, and then "site mods can escalate issues from their Meta site by adding the [status-review] tag".)

Comment: I'm confused about the process since the doc pages are probably the same on all the sites (that have MathJax), but well.

Comment: Me too:) They seem to allow small changes between sites, so I’m not sure how they apply changes that hold for all sites.

Comment: @Raphael: You're mostly right, in that the Markdown Editing Help page (located at `/editing-help` on a site) displays different sections depending on which relevant site settings are enabled on a site, and the LaTeX section is only displayed on sites with LaTeX enabled. But there's actually an additional site setting that determines which URL the "MathJax help" link at the bottom of that section points to...

Comment: As explained in [Shog9's answer to this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288209/335251), that Harvard Math website link is the default guidance that the "MathJax help" link points to. However, any site with MathJax enabled can request that a different link be used here – "ideally, they'll write one specific to the needs of their community, but if they want to link to Mathematics' guide instead that's fine too - as long as they don't mind it being specific to Math's needs in some ways (and, obviously, controlled by folks with editing rights on Math's meta)."

Comment: So... Would this community prefer to link to its own guide to using MathJax on CS.SE that focuses on what's relevant to CS.SE in particular (e.g. this FAQ: [Short reference for LaTeX/MathJax commands](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/141790))? Or should this just link to Math.SE's [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/414985)? – I'd suggest that the community here post/vote on answers below and come to a consensus on how to proceed. @Raphael The mods may also want to add the [featured] tag to make sure the community weighs in on this.

Comment: Hi all, I hope you will weigh in on the question V2Blast asked!  I look forward to hearing your perspectives!

Comment: It's been conveyed to me that Stack Exchange is unlikely to take action on this unless the community weighs in on this question, by posting answer(s) below and voting on them.  So, if this is something you care about, I encourage you to post an answer.